# ModuleNotFoundError with pyDataverse - API for Harvard Dataverse

Tags: python, installation, pip, modulenotfounderror, dataverse

I'm trying to use a Python API to access and download data the Harvard Dataverse. The [FAQs page for using APIs](https://guides.dataverse.org/en/4.6.1/api/client-libraries.html) to access the Dataverse suggests the [dataverse](https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-client-python) package, and the `.readme` for that GitHub repo points towards an alternative [pyDataverse](https://pydataverse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package. When I try to run and import these modules in a Jupyter Notebook I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` - but I have all the dependencies for these modules installed (`requests`, `jsonschema`, `urllib3`), so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
!pip install pyDataverse
import pyDataverse
```

Returns:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyDataverse'
```

And the same issue when I try the `dataverse` module - this module isn't available through PyPI so I ran `pip install -e git+https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-client-python.git#egg=dataverse` instead (see the [readme](https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-client-python)) and then ran `import dataverse` - which produced the same error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or alternative suggestions for APIs to access Dataverse repositories?

Comment: I don't believe `!pip install dataverse` worked — there is no such module at PyPI; https://pypi.org/project/dataverse/ returns Error 404. So the command to install was different. Please provide the exact command and its output and errors.

Comment: As for pyDataverse the [usage](https://pydataverse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quickstart) is different; the top-level module is `pyDataverse`

Comment: Sorry - I've edited my question to clarify. I found that going back to a Python 3.6 installation (instead of my usual Python 3.10) solved the issue: I could get `pyDataverse` to import without an error, but I still couldn't get `dataverse` to import. What I'm still confused about is how both modules seem to download and install without errors, but then when fail when imported into Python... Surely installing them to an incompatible version of Python should fail to begin with?

Comment: `pip install -e git+https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-client-python.git#egg=dataverse && python -c "import dataverse"` works for me.

Comment: When I try that in the terminal I no longer get the 'ModuleNotFoundError' - but if I switch back to a Jupyter Notebook and try `import dataverse` I get the error again. I tried running `!pip install -e git...` within the Jupyter Notebook and had no install errors but again when I ran `import dataverse` I get the same `ModuleNotFoundError`. Is there some reason why it seems to work in the terminal but not in Jupyter Notebook/Lab?

Comment: Possible if `!pip` is from a different Python (like `/usr/bin/python` for Jupyter Notebook and `/usr/local/bin/python` for `pip`; just example paths)